# Rotate an image in java?

Tags: java, rotation

I have been trying to rotate an image on a certain degree, and still remain on the same position. I have tried g.rotate, but it just rotate around a center, and it does not keep the same position as before. Any example to understand how it works would be great!

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example that demonstrates your problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), this will involve less guess work and produce better response

Comment: Use [rotate(double theta, double x, double y)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics2D.html#rotate-double-double-double-).

Answer (score 0):

When rotation occurs it happens relative to the origin of the screen (x=0, y=0). To make an image rotate relative to its center point you must first translate the image to the origin, perform the rotation, and then translate it back.